# Turn Slider into Touch on specific path IDs

Tags: javascript, css, touch-event

I'm trying to turn the slider function into a touch response. The SVG has specific path IDs that I want to reference to activate the same functions as the slider.

For instance. User taps on `I5` on the gear. The 5 left teeth then fill in red. If the user taps `I4` on the image, then 4 teeth (all in array `S4`, `S3`, `S2`, `S1`) fill in red. The same functions would happen on the right side of the gear, but fill in blue.

I appreciate your help and feedback.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Pinion Gear</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
    }

    

    .gear {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }

    .dia {
      fill: rgba(171,25,200, .86);
    }

    .imp::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      background: red;
    }

    .sup::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      background: blue;
    }

    .slidecontainer {
      width: 20%;
      padding-top: 0;
    }

    .impSlider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25px;
      background: #d3d3d3;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }

      .impSlider:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .impSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: red;
      }

    .supSlider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25px;
      background: #d3d3d3;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }

      .supSlider:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .supSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: blue;
      }

    .impSlider[type="range"] {
      transform: rotate(270deg);
      position: absolute;
      top: 200%;
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
    }

    .supSlider[type="range"] {
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="slidecontainer ">
          <input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" class="impSlider" id="impRange">
          <p>Importance: <span id="impOutput"></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="background">
         <svg width="220" height="220" viewBox="0 0 220 220" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="I5" d="M131.09 10L152.752 17.2953L148.108 57.9389C148.108 57.9389 137.487 51.3471 130.066 48.8479C122.645 46.3486 110.2 45.1722 110.2 45.1722L131.09 10Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S5" d="M67.2656 17.2926L88.9282 10L109.814 45.1748C109.814 45.1748 97.3685 46.3497 89.9473 48.848C82.5262 51.3463 71.9041 57.9369 71.9041 57.9369L67.2656 17.2926Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S4" d="M22.4805 58.7136L35.9529 40.249L73.3182 56.9014C73.3182 56.9014 63.8371 65.0483 59.2218 71.3739C54.6064 77.6995 49.7415 89.2145 49.7415 89.2145L22.4805 58.7136Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="I4" d="M184.592 40.8447L197.917 59.4165L170.413 89.6985C170.413 89.6985 165.64 78.1449 161.075 71.7826C156.511 65.4203 147.095 57.1978 147.095 57.1978L184.592 40.8447Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S3" d="M10 119.851V96.9943L50 88.4229C50 88.4229 47.1429 100.592 47.1429 108.422C47.1429 116.253 50 128.422 50 128.422L10 119.851Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="I3" d="M210 119.851V96.9943L170 88.4229C170 88.4229 172.857 100.592 172.857 108.422C172.857 116.253 170 128.422 170 128.422L210 119.851Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="I2" d="M184.045 176.593L197.518 158.128L170.257 127.627C170.257 127.627 165.392 139.142 160.776 145.468C156.161 151.794 146.68 159.941 146.68 159.941L184.045 176.593Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S2" d="M22.085 157.43L35.4093 176.002L72.9065 159.649C72.9065 159.649 63.4909 151.426 58.9263 145.064C54.3617 138.701 49.589 127.148 49.589 127.148L22.085 157.43Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S1" d="M67.251 199.545L88.9127 206.84L109.803 171.668C109.803 171.668 97.3575 170.492 89.9367 167.992C82.5158 165.493 71.8946 158.901 71.8946 158.901L67.251 199.545Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="I1" d="M131.076 206.843L152.738 199.55L148.1 158.906C148.1 158.906 137.478 165.497 130.056 167.995C122.635 170.493 110.19 171.668 110.19 171.668L131.076 206.843Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>

<path id="importance_i" d="M79.8428 153.002L80.7432 153.249L80.5247 153.34L83.4471 148.71L83.4688 148.93L82.8378 148.256L83.1591 147.747L85.4497 149.193L85.1285 149.702L84.257 149.428L84.457 149.347L81.5345 153.978L81.4986 153.725L82.1593 154.406L81.8381 154.916L79.5215 153.511L79.8428 153.002Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_m" d="M71.8207 144.773L71.9657 144.86C71.5219 144.869 71.1185 144.809 70.7557 144.68C70.3883 144.546 70.0937 144.37 69.872 144.153C69.5809 143.867 69.4313 143.534 69.4231 143.154C69.4149 142.775 69.6058 142.386 69.9956 141.989L72.0899 139.854L72.0506 140.061L71.6319 139.337L72.0534 138.907L73.8067 140.628L73.3851 141.057L72.7087 140.679L72.9418 140.65L71.004 142.625C70.7683 142.865 70.6446 143.093 70.6329 143.308C70.6212 143.523 70.6939 143.708 70.8509 143.862C70.9895 143.998 71.1828 144.106 71.4307 144.186C71.6695 144.266 71.9513 144.307 72.2763 144.308L72.0303 144.434C72.0574 144.388 72.0867 144.349 72.1185 144.317C72.1502 144.284 72.1797 144.254 72.2069 144.226L74.3351 142.057L74.2959 142.264L73.9326 141.594L74.3541 141.165L76.0519 142.831L75.6304 143.26L74.954 142.882L75.1871 142.853L73.2492 144.828C73.0135 145.068 72.8898 145.296 72.8781 145.511C72.8664 145.726 72.9391 145.911 73.0962 146.065C73.2302 146.196 73.4189 146.304 73.6622 146.389C73.9011 146.478 74.1761 146.521 74.4873 146.518L74.2957 146.589L76.6008 144.24L76.5548 144.453L76.1847 143.804L76.6063 143.375L78.3596 145.095L77.938 145.525L77.1856 145.099L77.412 145.076L74.7126 147.828L74.7446 147.587L75.1842 148.331L74.7626 148.761L73.5717 147.701L74.1204 146.92L74.1905 147.071C73.7511 147.075 73.3546 147.012 73.001 146.883C72.6382 146.753 72.3436 146.578 72.1172 146.356C71.9047 146.147 71.7674 145.908 71.7054 145.639C71.6433 145.369 71.6818 145.08 71.8207 144.773Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_p" d="M70.615 133.621L70.1212 133.966L69.431 133.417L69.6871 133.428L64.718 136.894L64.7701 136.68L65.0645 137.492L64.5708 137.837L63.5963 136.575L64.2114 135.98L64.2278 136.123C63.8345 136.034 63.4962 135.911 63.2128 135.754C62.9294 135.596 62.7007 135.393 62.5267 135.143C62.3119 134.835 62.2054 134.507 62.2071 134.159C62.2034 133.814 62.3146 133.464 62.5406 133.109C62.7575 132.753 63.0916 132.417 63.5429 132.103C64.0526 131.747 64.5384 131.539 65.0003 131.477C65.4585 131.41 65.8845 131.472 66.2781 131.663C66.6627 131.852 66.9994 132.154 67.2882 132.568C67.3845 132.706 67.472 132.854 67.5507 133.012C67.6294 133.171 67.7084 133.34 67.7876 133.522L67.5793 133.478L69.0207 132.473L68.9471 132.69L68.5996 131.784L69.0933 131.439L70.615 133.621ZM66.6867 133.165C66.4053 132.762 66.0607 132.556 65.653 132.549C65.2453 132.541 64.8051 132.702 64.3327 133.031C64.0247 133.246 63.7871 133.471 63.6196 133.706C63.4485 133.936 63.35 134.163 63.3241 134.386C63.2983 134.609 63.3539 134.819 63.4909 135.015C63.5982 135.169 63.7536 135.301 63.957 135.412C64.1515 135.521 64.3965 135.607 64.6923 135.669L64.3462 135.732L67.1971 133.744L67.0893 133.997C66.9764 133.665 66.8422 133.388 66.6867 133.165Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_o" d="M58.2145 124.978C58.0543 124.244 58.1513 123.627 58.5055 123.126C58.852 122.619 59.4299 122.278 60.2393 122.101C60.8021 121.978 61.3079 121.973 61.7568 122.087C62.2043 122.195 62.5795 122.411 62.8823 122.736C63.1837 123.054 63.3911 123.473 63.5044 123.991C63.6632 124.718 63.5687 125.332 63.2208 125.832C62.8716 126.326 62.2891 126.662 61.4734 126.84C60.9106 126.963 60.4055 126.97 59.958 126.863C59.5104 126.755 59.136 126.542 58.8345 126.224C58.5331 125.905 58.3264 125.49 58.2145 124.978ZM59.0427 124.857C59.1297 125.255 59.3509 125.525 59.7063 125.666C60.0604 125.8 60.5441 125.801 61.1574 125.667C61.7708 125.533 62.1983 125.337 62.4401 125.078C62.6818 124.82 62.7605 124.498 62.6762 124.113C62.6154 123.834 62.4955 123.619 62.3163 123.466C62.1308 123.314 61.8917 123.221 61.5991 123.185C61.3002 123.151 60.9515 123.178 60.5532 123.265C59.9588 123.394 59.5389 123.596 59.2937 123.868C59.0407 124.135 58.957 124.465 59.0427 124.857Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_r" d="M61.9024 115.15L61.3011 115.177L61.0512 114.382L61.2408 114.49L57.3613 114.665L57.5588 114.52L57.3731 115.355L56.7718 115.382L56.6222 113.795L57.5462 113.598L57.5144 113.755C57.1974 113.477 56.9517 113.204 56.7775 112.933C56.5965 112.656 56.4985 112.353 56.4835 112.023C56.4742 111.816 56.4967 111.598 56.5511 111.369L58.2228 111.371L58.2535 112.05L57.2219 112.232L57.4499 112.115C57.4387 112.155 57.4309 112.197 57.4265 112.243C57.4221 112.288 57.4209 112.334 57.4229 112.379C57.4329 112.599 57.5106 112.812 57.656 113.019C57.7947 113.22 57.9746 113.4 58.1956 113.559L57.8711 113.476L61.188 113.326L61.0104 113.48L61.1789 112.481L61.7802 112.453L61.9024 115.15Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_t" d="M62.8086 102.69C62.7672 103.096 62.6129 103.395 62.3458 103.589C62.0724 103.783 61.6877 103.854 61.1919 103.803L58.053 103.482L58.234 103.335L58.1362 104.291L57.5084 104.227L57.414 103.241L57.5991 103.436L56.2952 103.302L56.2119 102.113L57.7185 102.267L57.5405 102.386L57.6926 100.898L58.4729 100.998L58.3228 102.466L58.1725 102.314L61.1569 102.619C61.4337 102.647 61.6383 102.619 61.7705 102.535C61.9027 102.451 61.978 102.319 61.9965 102.139C62.0077 102.029 62.0005 101.908 61.975 101.775C61.9496 101.642 61.9154 101.499 61.8726 101.345L62.5328 101.188C62.7641 101.726 62.856 102.226 62.8086 102.69Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_a" d="M64.1292 91.7049L63.8591 91.8138L64.3067 91.0388L64.8883 91.1938L64.5535 92.7523L63.6129 92.6625L63.661 92.5949C63.8991 92.933 64.0524 93.2753 64.1209 93.6217C64.191 93.9619 64.1861 94.2821 64.1061 94.5823C64.0045 94.9638 63.7967 95.2534 63.4828 95.4511C63.1626 95.6471 62.7649 95.6818 62.2896 95.5552C61.9268 95.4585 61.6631 95.3045 61.4984 95.0932C61.3336 94.8819 61.245 94.6238 61.2324 94.319C61.2152 94.0063 61.2608 93.6467 61.3691 93.2402L61.6566 92.1614L61.7373 92.2733L61.0243 92.0833C60.7178 92.0017 60.4781 92.0215 60.3051 92.1429C60.1258 92.2626 59.9979 92.4663 59.9212 92.754C59.8829 92.8978 59.8577 93.0552 59.8457 93.2262C59.829 93.3892 59.827 93.5729 59.8396 93.7771L59.7338 93.6083L60.5012 93.9333L60.3088 94.6557L58.9754 94.3808C58.9649 93.9427 58.9765 93.5472 59.0102 93.1945C59.0376 92.8401 59.0896 92.519 59.1663 92.2313C59.3129 91.681 59.5482 91.2882 59.8721 91.053C60.1897 90.8161 60.605 90.766 61.1178 90.9026L64.1292 91.7049ZM62.4888 94.3926C62.739 94.4592 62.9393 94.4489 63.0898 94.3618C63.2403 94.2746 63.3405 94.1372 63.3905 93.9496C63.4388 93.7682 63.435 93.5562 63.3791 93.3136C63.3232 93.0709 63.2281 92.8245 63.0938 92.5744L63.3039 92.6907L62.1876 92.3933L62.3039 92.3338L62.0639 93.2344C61.9656 93.6034 61.9536 93.8749 62.0278 94.0487C62.1038 94.2163 62.2574 94.3309 62.4888 94.3926Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_n" d="M66.9267 86.3497L66.384 86.0894L66.5437 85.24L66.6383 85.4468L63.163 83.7802L63.401 83.7328L62.8386 84.3891L62.2959 84.1288L62.9144 82.6596L63.8307 82.9268L63.711 83.0416C63.5563 82.6157 63.4874 82.213 63.5043 81.8335C63.5154 81.4512 63.5895 81.1171 63.7267 80.8311C63.9142 80.4401 64.1921 80.175 64.5603 80.0357C64.9314 79.8907 65.3635 79.94 65.8568 80.1837L68.5443 81.4725L68.3363 81.502L68.8861 80.872L69.4288 81.1323L68.3541 83.3733L67.8114 83.113L67.9634 82.3245L68.0667 82.5356L65.5806 81.3433C65.2713 81.195 65.0101 81.1559 64.797 81.226C64.5868 81.2902 64.4271 81.4362 64.3179 81.6638C64.2339 81.8389 64.1912 82.0552 64.1897 82.3129C64.1823 82.5678 64.2288 82.8449 64.3293 83.1443L64.2007 82.9858L67.1683 84.409L66.9516 84.4342L67.4587 83.8484L68.0015 84.1086L66.9267 86.3497Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_c" d="M73.6657 76.0512C73.3541 76.362 73.0014 76.5675 72.6077 76.6677C72.214 76.7679 71.8067 76.7491 71.3858 76.6113C70.9649 76.4735 70.5579 76.2075 70.1648 75.8134C69.8129 75.4606 69.5662 75.1125 69.4247 74.7691C69.2787 74.421 69.215 74.0869 69.2337 73.7665C69.2524 73.437 69.3352 73.1305 69.482 72.8469C69.6288 72.5542 69.8168 72.2936 70.0459 72.065C70.2521 71.8593 70.4926 71.6743 70.7674 71.5098C71.0376 71.3408 71.2849 71.2221 71.5093 71.1538L72.4348 72.1366L71.8987 72.6714L71.2128 72.1763L71.3433 72.1696C71.2196 72.2198 71.0937 72.2906 70.9654 72.3819C70.8417 72.4687 70.7364 72.5556 70.6493 72.6424C70.4385 72.8527 70.3147 73.0859 70.2777 73.3422C70.2408 73.5893 70.2817 73.8456 70.4004 74.1112C70.519 74.3768 70.7109 74.6425 70.976 74.9083C71.2594 75.1924 71.5361 75.3918 71.806 75.5065C72.0804 75.6167 72.3411 75.6491 72.5883 75.6036C72.8355 75.5582 73.0532 75.4417 73.2411 75.2543C73.3923 75.1035 73.5229 74.9091 73.6331 74.6713C73.7432 74.4334 73.8305 74.1589 73.895 73.8478L74.595 73.9997C74.5395 74.439 74.4315 74.8302 74.2709 75.1732C74.1103 75.5163 73.9086 75.8089 73.6657 76.0512Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_e" d="M80.0465 70.015C79.6423 70.2196 79.2404 70.3143 78.8409 70.2989C78.4384 70.2778 78.0629 70.1378 77.7142 69.8791C77.3656 69.6203 77.0641 69.2397 76.8098 68.7373C76.5496 68.2234 76.4154 67.7363 76.4073 67.2762C76.405 66.813 76.5187 66.4 76.7485 66.037C76.9811 65.6653 77.3255 65.364 77.7816 65.1331C78.2147 64.9138 78.6123 64.825 78.9743 64.8666C79.3392 64.8995 79.6655 65.0353 79.9533 65.2742C80.241 65.513 80.4829 65.8258 80.6787 66.2127C80.7226 66.2993 80.7636 66.3874 80.8016 66.4769C80.8397 66.5665 80.8764 66.6676 80.9117 66.7803L77.6895 68.4116L77.3562 67.7533L79.6689 66.5825L79.5871 66.7218C79.476 66.4879 79.3447 66.2932 79.1934 66.1377C79.0479 65.9792 78.881 65.8787 78.6926 65.8362C78.5043 65.7938 78.3004 65.8281 78.0809 65.9392C77.8326 66.0649 77.6627 66.2379 77.5712 66.4584C77.4854 66.6759 77.465 66.9221 77.5098 67.1968C77.5603 67.4687 77.6616 67.7547 77.8137 68.055C77.9803 68.3841 78.1712 68.6538 78.3865 68.864C78.5988 69.0685 78.8339 69.1961 79.0918 69.2469C79.3497 69.2977 79.6201 69.2515 79.903 69.1083C80.1051 69.0059 80.3056 68.8573 80.5043 68.6624C80.7031 68.4675 80.89 68.2277 81.0651 67.9432L81.7053 68.3264C81.4902 68.7182 81.2415 69.0581 80.9593 69.3461C80.6741 69.6283 80.3699 69.8513 80.0465 70.015Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="support_s" d="M151.387 71.782C151.204 71.9014 151.09 72.0573 151.045 72.2497C151.006 72.4384 151.006 72.6501 151.046 72.8848C151.089 73.1252 151.146 73.3808 151.218 73.6517C151.298 73.9246 151.367 74.1973 151.423 74.47C151.483 74.7483 151.507 75.0216 151.496 75.2899C151.488 75.5639 151.418 75.8251 151.288 76.0734C151.163 76.3181 150.949 76.5393 150.647 76.737C150.231 77.0094 149.818 77.125 149.408 77.0837C149.002 77.0481 148.616 76.8936 148.25 76.6202C147.887 76.3525 147.566 76.0049 147.286 75.5772C147.092 75.2807 146.924 74.9552 146.781 74.6005C146.637 74.2553 146.527 73.8953 146.453 73.5204L148.038 72.5445L148.441 73.1603L147.486 74.0168L147.607 73.7911C147.641 74.0295 147.701 74.2634 147.786 74.4928C147.876 74.7185 147.983 74.9254 148.106 75.1136C148.259 75.3474 148.429 75.5378 148.615 75.6849C148.81 75.834 149.011 75.9227 149.216 75.9509C149.428 75.9754 149.633 75.9223 149.833 75.7917C150.027 75.6648 150.146 75.5052 150.191 75.3128C150.246 75.1224 150.252 74.907 150.208 74.6666C150.174 74.4281 150.116 74.1772 150.033 73.9138C149.956 73.6466 149.885 73.3758 149.819 73.1011C149.759 72.8228 149.73 72.5485 149.732 72.2782C149.744 72.01 149.81 71.7554 149.929 71.5145C150.058 71.2755 150.276 71.0553 150.584 70.8538C150.971 70.6001 151.352 70.4852 151.726 70.5092C152.106 70.5294 152.465 70.661 152.803 70.9039C153.147 71.1431 153.451 71.4651 153.716 71.8699C153.903 72.155 154.066 72.472 154.204 72.821C154.353 73.1719 154.465 73.5424 154.541 73.9324L153.039 74.7928L152.625 74.1598L153.485 73.3649L153.441 73.5771C153.403 73.3821 153.343 73.185 153.262 72.9859C153.184 72.7924 153.087 72.6073 152.972 72.4306C152.837 72.2253 152.682 72.0501 152.505 71.905C152.335 71.7561 152.154 71.6667 151.963 71.6367C151.773 71.6067 151.58 71.6552 151.387 71.782Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_u" d="M154.316 84.5026C154.151 84.0768 154.147 83.6693 154.303 83.28C154.468 82.8946 154.827 82.5949 155.38 82.3809L158.249 81.2702L158.122 81.451L158.038 80.5845L158.629 80.3557L159.397 82.141L156.013 83.451C155.689 83.5764 155.476 83.743 155.374 83.9506C155.28 84.1622 155.281 84.3919 155.377 84.6397C155.451 84.8304 155.583 85.0204 155.773 85.2098C155.964 85.3992 156.214 85.5653 156.525 85.7079L156.273 85.707L159.514 84.4524L159.358 84.6443L159.274 83.7778L159.865 83.549L160.633 85.3343L156.153 87.0686L156.288 86.8518L156.386 87.7565L155.795 87.9852L155.124 86.4478L155.995 85.9241L156.001 86.1083C155.566 85.9111 155.206 85.6704 154.921 85.3863C154.638 85.1086 154.436 84.814 154.316 84.5026Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_p" d="M156.372 93.6086L156.998 93.5081L157.401 94.344L157.163 94.2166L163.461 93.2055L163.314 93.3844L163.406 92.4792L164.032 92.3787L164.379 94.0209L163.523 94.3032L163.573 94.1606C163.905 94.4248 164.17 94.6963 164.366 94.9753C164.563 95.2543 164.687 95.5519 164.737 95.8682C164.8 96.2584 164.751 96.6183 164.59 96.9478C164.435 97.2762 164.17 97.557 163.793 97.79C163.424 98.0287 162.954 98.1939 162.382 98.2857C161.736 98.3894 161.18 98.3648 160.714 98.2119C160.249 98.0658 159.873 97.812 159.588 97.4507C159.31 97.0951 159.128 96.6548 159.044 96.13C159.016 95.9551 159.001 95.7746 158.999 95.5887C158.996 95.4027 158.999 95.2055 159.007 94.9972L159.185 95.1344L157.358 95.4277L157.527 95.2556L157.442 96.2734L156.816 96.3739L156.372 93.6086ZM159.888 95.8393C159.97 96.3506 160.203 96.7032 160.586 96.8971C160.969 97.0909 161.46 97.1398 162.058 97.0436C162.449 96.981 162.777 96.8765 163.043 96.7302C163.311 96.5907 163.508 96.421 163.635 96.2212C163.761 96.0214 163.805 95.7971 163.765 95.5481C163.733 95.353 163.647 95.1564 163.504 94.9584C163.37 94.7661 163.177 94.5728 162.925 94.3786L163.282 94.4765L159.669 95.0566L159.887 94.8663C159.842 95.2324 159.842 95.5567 159.888 95.8393Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_p" d="M156.903 105.184L157.536 105.212L157.762 106.113L157.555 105.94L163.927 106.224L163.747 106.369L164.021 105.502L164.654 105.53L164.661 107.208L163.766 107.312L163.843 107.182C164.115 107.508 164.319 107.827 164.455 108.14C164.591 108.453 164.652 108.77 164.638 109.09C164.62 109.485 164.499 109.827 164.275 110.117C164.058 110.408 163.741 110.629 163.325 110.781C162.915 110.94 162.421 111.007 161.842 110.981C161.189 110.952 160.649 110.815 160.224 110.571C159.798 110.334 159.481 110.009 159.275 109.597C159.074 109.193 158.986 108.725 159.01 108.194C159.018 108.017 159.039 107.837 159.075 107.655C159.11 107.472 159.153 107.28 159.203 107.077L159.349 107.247L157.5 107.165L157.701 107.031L157.412 108.01L156.778 107.982L156.903 105.184ZM159.895 108.08C159.872 108.598 160.028 108.99 160.364 109.257C160.7 109.525 161.171 109.672 161.777 109.699C162.172 109.716 162.514 109.681 162.805 109.591C163.095 109.509 163.322 109.382 163.487 109.212C163.651 109.042 163.739 108.831 163.75 108.58C163.759 108.382 163.714 108.172 163.615 107.949C163.522 107.734 163.372 107.505 163.164 107.264L163.494 107.432L159.839 107.269L160.091 107.127C159.973 107.477 159.907 107.794 159.895 108.08Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_o" d="M162.938 121.459C162.744 122.225 162.362 122.761 161.793 123.067C161.228 123.38 160.523 123.43 159.677 123.216C159.09 123.067 158.611 122.833 158.242 122.514C157.871 122.202 157.619 121.822 157.487 121.374C157.353 120.932 157.355 120.44 157.492 119.899C157.685 119.139 158.063 118.606 158.625 118.299C159.187 117.998 159.893 117.956 160.746 118.172C161.333 118.321 161.813 118.552 162.184 118.863C162.554 119.175 162.807 119.552 162.941 119.994C163.075 120.436 163.074 120.924 162.938 121.459ZM162.101 121.184C162.207 120.767 162.125 120.409 161.857 120.109C161.587 119.816 161.132 119.588 160.491 119.425C159.85 119.263 159.355 119.246 159.006 119.376C158.657 119.505 158.431 119.771 158.329 120.174C158.255 120.465 158.267 120.724 158.364 120.953C158.467 121.183 158.648 121.384 158.907 121.555C159.173 121.727 159.513 121.867 159.929 121.972C160.55 122.13 161.04 122.138 161.4 121.997C161.764 121.864 161.998 121.593 162.101 121.184Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_r" d="M154.532 129.675L155.069 130.011L154.81 130.85L154.71 130.643L158.176 132.811L157.918 132.819L158.578 132.207L159.116 132.543L158.296 134.008L157.377 133.626L157.499 133.509C157.608 133.939 157.656 134.323 157.645 134.662C157.637 135.01 157.54 135.331 157.356 135.626C157.24 135.811 157.09 135.986 156.906 136.152L155.459 135.15L155.838 134.544L156.841 135.003L156.574 134.968C156.607 134.94 156.639 134.908 156.67 134.871C156.701 134.835 156.73 134.796 156.755 134.756C156.878 134.559 156.938 134.328 156.936 134.061C156.936 133.804 156.888 133.541 156.791 133.271L157.023 133.537L154.059 131.683L154.305 131.656L153.562 132.42L153.025 132.084L154.532 129.675Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_t" d="M146.526 140.751C146.77 140.398 147.064 140.199 147.409 140.156C147.759 140.117 148.15 140.246 148.582 140.545L151.314 142.434L151.073 142.478L151.648 141.646L152.195 142.024L151.781 142.981L151.71 142.707L152.845 143.492L152.318 144.631L151.006 143.724L151.23 143.706L150.335 145L149.666 144.513L150.549 143.235L150.611 143.451L148.013 141.655C147.772 141.488 147.569 141.41 147.405 141.421C147.24 141.431 147.103 141.515 146.995 141.672C146.929 141.767 146.874 141.882 146.83 142.018C146.786 142.153 146.745 142.303 146.706 142.466L146.018 142.276C146.077 141.663 146.247 141.154 146.526 140.751Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="diamond" d="M73.6465 108.253L110.253 71.6465L146.859 108.253L110.253 144.859L73.6465 108.253Z" fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="#8A2BE2" stroke-width="2.32854"/>

<path id="P" d="M101.563 121.882H106.718V112.268H112.164C118.735 112.268 122.264 108.322 122.264 102.848C122.264 97.4156 118.777 93.4282 112.233 93.4282H101.563V121.882ZM106.718 108.03V97.7351H111.441C115.304 97.7351 117.013 99.8191 117.013 102.848C117.013 105.877 115.304 108.03 111.469 108.03H106.718Z" fill="#8A2BE2"/>

</svg>
        </div>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
          <input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" class="supSlider" id="supRange">
          <p>Support: <span id="supOutput"></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>
    </div>
  
  <script>
    var scoreInt = 0;
    var score = document.getElementById("score");
    var impSlider = document.getElementById("impRange");
    var impOutput = document.getElementById("impOutput");
    impSlider.oninput = function () {
      impOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
      scoreInt = parseInt(impOutput.innerHTML) * parseInt(supOutput.innerHTML);
      score.innerHTML = scoreInt.toString();
      switch (this.value) {
        case "0":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "1":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "2":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "3":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "4":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "5":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "red";
          break;
      }

    }
    impOutput.innerHTML = impSlider.value;

    var supSlider = document.getElementById("supRange");
    var supOutput = document.getElementById("supOutput");

    supSlider.oninput = function () {
      supOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
      scoreInt = parseInt(impOutput.innerHTML) * parseInt(supOutput.innerHTML);
      score.innerHTML = scoreInt.toString();
      switch (this.value) {
         case "0":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
          case "1":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "2":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "3":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "4":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "5":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "blue";
          break;
      }
    }
    supOutput.innerHTML = supSlider.value;
  </script>

<script>
        var a = document.getElementById("S1");
        //it's important to add an load event listener to the object, as it will load the svg doc asynchronously
        a.addEventListener("load",function(){
            var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM of "S1"
            var delta = svgDoc.getElementById("delta"); //get the inner element by id
            delta.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){alert('bounce')},false);    //add behaviour
        },false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

so the issue is with your code.

in the `supSlider.oninput` event of this, if you try to modify the DOM, it causes an error and ends up breaking your code.

anyway, look at this [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zbdusntr/1/)

also here is the code.

## HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Pinion Gear</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="slidecontainer ">
          <input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" class="impSlider" id="impRange">
          <p>Importance: <span id="impOutput"></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="background">
         <svg width="220" height="220" viewBox="0 0 220 220" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="I5" d="M131.09 10L152.752 17.2953L148.108 57.9389C148.108 57.9389 137.487 51.3471 130.066 48.8479C122.645 46.3486 110.2 45.1722 110.2 45.1722L131.09 10Z" stroke="#454545" staroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S5" d="M67.2656 17.2926L88.9282 10L109.814 45.1748C109.814 45.1748 97.3685 46.3497 89.9473 48.848C82.5262 51.3463 71.9041 57.9369 71.9041 57.9369L67.2656 17.2926Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S4" d="M22.4805 58.7136L35.9529 40.249L73.3182 56.9014C73.3182 56.9014 63.8371 65.0483 59.2218 71.3739C54.6064 77.6995 49.7415 89.2145 49.7415 89.2145L22.4805 58.7136Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="I4" d="M184.592 40.8447L197.917 59.4165L170.413 89.6985C170.413 89.6985 165.64 78.1449 161.075 71.7826C156.511 65.4203 147.095 57.1978 147.095 57.1978L184.592 40.8447Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S3" d="M10 119.851V96.9943L50 88.4229C50 88.4229 47.1429 100.592 47.1429 108.422C47.1429 116.253 50 128.422 50 128.422L10 119.851Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="I3" d="M210 119.851V96.9943L170 88.4229C170 88.4229 172.857 100.592 172.857 108.422C172.857 116.253 170 128.422 170 128.422L210 119.851Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="I2" d="M184.045 176.593L197.518 158.128L170.257 127.627C170.257 127.627 165.392 139.142 160.776 145.468C156.161 151.794 146.68 159.941 146.68 159.941L184.045 176.593Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S2" d="M22.085 157.43L35.4093 176.002L72.9065 159.649C72.9065 159.649 63.4909 151.426 58.9263 145.064C54.3617 138.701 49.589 127.148 49.589 127.148L22.085 157.43Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="S1" d="M67.251 199.545L88.9127 206.84L109.803 171.668C109.803 171.668 97.3575 170.492 89.9367 167.992C82.5158 165.493 71.8946 158.901 71.8946 158.901L67.251 199.545Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>
<path id="I1" d="M131.076 206.843L152.738 199.55L148.1 158.906C148.1 158.906 137.478 165.497 130.056 167.995C122.635 170.493 110.19 171.668 110.19 171.668L131.076 206.843Z" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="3.65"/>

<path id="importance_i" d="M79.8428 153.002L80.7432 153.249L80.5247 153.34L83.4471 148.71L83.4688 148.93L82.8378 148.256L83.1591 147.747L85.4497 149.193L85.1285 149.702L84.257 149.428L84.457 149.347L81.5345 153.978L81.4986 153.725L82.1593 154.406L81.8381 154.916L79.5215 153.511L79.8428 153.002Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_m" d="M71.8207 144.773L71.9657 144.86C71.5219 144.869 71.1185 144.809 70.7557 144.68C70.3883 144.546 70.0937 144.37 69.872 144.153C69.5809 143.867 69.4313 143.534 69.4231 143.154C69.4149 142.775 69.6058 142.386 69.9956 141.989L72.0899 139.854L72.0506 140.061L71.6319 139.337L72.0534 138.907L73.8067 140.628L73.3851 141.057L72.7087 140.679L72.9418 140.65L71.004 142.625C70.7683 142.865 70.6446 143.093 70.6329 143.308C70.6212 143.523 70.6939 143.708 70.8509 143.862C70.9895 143.998 71.1828 144.106 71.4307 144.186C71.6695 144.266 71.9513 144.307 72.2763 144.308L72.0303 144.434C72.0574 144.388 72.0867 144.349 72.1185 144.317C72.1502 144.284 72.1797 144.254 72.2069 144.226L74.3351 142.057L74.2959 142.264L73.9326 141.594L74.3541 141.165L76.0519 142.831L75.6304 143.26L74.954 142.882L75.1871 142.853L73.2492 144.828C73.0135 145.068 72.8898 145.296 72.8781 145.511C72.8664 145.726 72.9391 145.911 73.0962 146.065C73.2302 146.196 73.4189 146.304 73.6622 146.389C73.9011 146.478 74.1761 146.521 74.4873 146.518L74.2957 146.589L76.6008 144.24L76.5548 144.453L76.1847 143.804L76.6063 143.375L78.3596 145.095L77.938 145.525L77.1856 145.099L77.412 145.076L74.7126 147.828L74.7446 147.587L75.1842 148.331L74.7626 148.761L73.5717 147.701L74.1204 146.92L74.1905 147.071C73.7511 147.075 73.3546 147.012 73.001 146.883C72.6382 146.753 72.3436 146.578 72.1172 146.356C71.9047 146.147 71.7674 145.908 71.7054 145.639C71.6433 145.369 71.6818 145.08 71.8207 144.773Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_p" d="M70.615 133.621L70.1212 133.966L69.431 133.417L69.6871 133.428L64.718 136.894L64.7701 136.68L65.0645 137.492L64.5708 137.837L63.5963 136.575L64.2114 135.98L64.2278 136.123C63.8345 136.034 63.4962 135.911 63.2128 135.754C62.9294 135.596 62.7007 135.393 62.5267 135.143C62.3119 134.835 62.2054 134.507 62.2071 134.159C62.2034 133.814 62.3146 133.464 62.5406 133.109C62.7575 132.753 63.0916 132.417 63.5429 132.103C64.0526 131.747 64.5384 131.539 65.0003 131.477C65.4585 131.41 65.8845 131.472 66.2781 131.663C66.6627 131.852 66.9994 132.154 67.2882 132.568C67.3845 132.706 67.472 132.854 67.5507 133.012C67.6294 133.171 67.7084 133.34 67.7876 133.522L67.5793 133.478L69.0207 132.473L68.9471 132.69L68.5996 131.784L69.0933 131.439L70.615 133.621ZM66.6867 133.165C66.4053 132.762 66.0607 132.556 65.653 132.549C65.2453 132.541 64.8051 132.702 64.3327 133.031C64.0247 133.246 63.7871 133.471 63.6196 133.706C63.4485 133.936 63.35 134.163 63.3241 134.386C63.2983 134.609 63.3539 134.819 63.4909 135.015C63.5982 135.169 63.7536 135.301 63.957 135.412C64.1515 135.521 64.3965 135.607 64.6923 135.669L64.3462 135.732L67.1971 133.744L67.0893 133.997C66.9764 133.665 66.8422 133.388 66.6867 133.165Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_o" d="M58.2145 124.978C58.0543 124.244 58.1513 123.627 58.5055 123.126C58.852 122.619 59.4299 122.278 60.2393 122.101C60.8021 121.978 61.3079 121.973 61.7568 122.087C62.2043 122.195 62.5795 122.411 62.8823 122.736C63.1837 123.054 63.3911 123.473 63.5044 123.991C63.6632 124.718 63.5687 125.332 63.2208 125.832C62.8716 126.326 62.2891 126.662 61.4734 126.84C60.9106 126.963 60.4055 126.97 59.958 126.863C59.5104 126.755 59.136 126.542 58.8345 126.224C58.5331 125.905 58.3264 125.49 58.2145 124.978ZM59.0427 124.857C59.1297 125.255 59.3509 125.525 59.7063 125.666C60.0604 125.8 60.5441 125.801 61.1574 125.667C61.7708 125.533 62.1983 125.337 62.4401 125.078C62.6818 124.82 62.7605 124.498 62.6762 124.113C62.6154 123.834 62.4955 123.619 62.3163 123.466C62.1308 123.314 61.8917 123.221 61.5991 123.185C61.3002 123.151 60.9515 123.178 60.5532 123.265C59.9588 123.394 59.5389 123.596 59.2937 123.868C59.0407 124.135 58.957 124.465 59.0427 124.857Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_r" d="M61.9024 115.15L61.3011 115.177L61.0512 114.382L61.2408 114.49L57.3613 114.665L57.5588 114.52L57.3731 115.355L56.7718 115.382L56.6222 113.795L57.5462 113.598L57.5144 113.755C57.1974 113.477 56.9517 113.204 56.7775 112.933C56.5965 112.656 56.4985 112.353 56.4835 112.023C56.4742 111.816 56.4967 111.598 56.5511 111.369L58.2228 111.371L58.2535 112.05L57.2219 112.232L57.4499 112.115C57.4387 112.155 57.4309 112.197 57.4265 112.243C57.4221 112.288 57.4209 112.334 57.4229 112.379C57.4329 112.599 57.5106 112.812 57.656 113.019C57.7947 113.22 57.9746 113.4 58.1956 113.559L57.8711 113.476L61.188 113.326L61.0104 113.48L61.1789 112.481L61.7802 112.453L61.9024 115.15Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_t" d="M62.8086 102.69C62.7672 103.096 62.6129 103.395 62.3458 103.589C62.0724 103.783 61.6877 103.854 61.1919 103.803L58.053 103.482L58.234 103.335L58.1362 104.291L57.5084 104.227L57.414 103.241L57.5991 103.436L56.2952 103.302L56.2119 102.113L57.7185 102.267L57.5405 102.386L57.6926 100.898L58.4729 100.998L58.3228 102.466L58.1725 102.314L61.1569 102.619C61.4337 102.647 61.6383 102.619 61.7705 102.535C61.9027 102.451 61.978 102.319 61.9965 102.139C62.0077 102.029 62.0005 101.908 61.975 101.775C61.9496 101.642 61.9154 101.499 61.8726 101.345L62.5328 101.188C62.7641 101.726 62.856 102.226 62.8086 102.69Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_a" d="M64.1292 91.7049L63.8591 91.8138L64.3067 91.0388L64.8883 91.1938L64.5535 92.7523L63.6129 92.6625L63.661 92.5949C63.8991 92.933 64.0524 93.2753 64.1209 93.6217C64.191 93.9619 64.1861 94.2821 64.1061 94.5823C64.0045 94.9638 63.7967 95.2534 63.4828 95.4511C63.1626 95.6471 62.7649 95.6818 62.2896 95.5552C61.9268 95.4585 61.6631 95.3045 61.4984 95.0932C61.3336 94.8819 61.245 94.6238 61.2324 94.319C61.2152 94.0063 61.2608 93.6467 61.3691 93.2402L61.6566 92.1614L61.7373 92.2733L61.0243 92.0833C60.7178 92.0017 60.4781 92.0215 60.3051 92.1429C60.1258 92.2626 59.9979 92.4663 59.9212 92.754C59.8829 92.8978 59.8577 93.0552 59.8457 93.2262C59.829 93.3892 59.827 93.5729 59.8396 93.7771L59.7338 93.6083L60.5012 93.9333L60.3088 94.6557L58.9754 94.3808C58.9649 93.9427 58.9765 93.5472 59.0102 93.1945C59.0376 92.8401 59.0896 92.519 59.1663 92.2313C59.3129 91.681 59.5482 91.2882 59.8721 91.053C60.1897 90.8161 60.605 90.766 61.1178 90.9026L64.1292 91.7049ZM62.4888 94.3926C62.739 94.4592 62.9393 94.4489 63.0898 94.3618C63.2403 94.2746 63.3405 94.1372 63.3905 93.9496C63.4388 93.7682 63.435 93.5562 63.3791 93.3136C63.3232 93.0709 63.2281 92.8245 63.0938 92.5744L63.3039 92.6907L62.1876 92.3933L62.3039 92.3338L62.0639 93.2344C61.9656 93.6034 61.9536 93.8749 62.0278 94.0487C62.1038 94.2163 62.2574 94.3309 62.4888 94.3926Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_n" d="M66.9267 86.3497L66.384 86.0894L66.5437 85.24L66.6383 85.4468L63.163 83.7802L63.401 83.7328L62.8386 84.3891L62.2959 84.1288L62.9144 82.6596L63.8307 82.9268L63.711 83.0416C63.5563 82.6157 63.4874 82.213 63.5043 81.8335C63.5154 81.4512 63.5895 81.1171 63.7267 80.8311C63.9142 80.4401 64.1921 80.175 64.5603 80.0357C64.9314 79.8907 65.3635 79.94 65.8568 80.1837L68.5443 81.4725L68.3363 81.502L68.8861 80.872L69.4288 81.1323L68.3541 83.3733L67.8114 83.113L67.9634 82.3245L68.0667 82.5356L65.5806 81.3433C65.2713 81.195 65.0101 81.1559 64.797 81.226C64.5868 81.2902 64.4271 81.4362 64.3179 81.6638C64.2339 81.8389 64.1912 82.0552 64.1897 82.3129C64.1823 82.5678 64.2288 82.8449 64.3293 83.1443L64.2007 82.9858L67.1683 84.409L66.9516 84.4342L67.4587 83.8484L68.0015 84.1086L66.9267 86.3497Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_c" d="M73.6657 76.0512C73.3541 76.362 73.0014 76.5675 72.6077 76.6677C72.214 76.7679 71.8067 76.7491 71.3858 76.6113C70.9649 76.4735 70.5579 76.2075 70.1648 75.8134C69.8129 75.4606 69.5662 75.1125 69.4247 74.7691C69.2787 74.421 69.215 74.0869 69.2337 73.7665C69.2524 73.437 69.3352 73.1305 69.482 72.8469C69.6288 72.5542 69.8168 72.2936 70.0459 72.065C70.2521 71.8593 70.4926 71.6743 70.7674 71.5098C71.0376 71.3408 71.2849 71.2221 71.5093 71.1538L72.4348 72.1366L71.8987 72.6714L71.2128 72.1763L71.3433 72.1696C71.2196 72.2198 71.0937 72.2906 70.9654 72.3819C70.8417 72.4687 70.7364 72.5556 70.6493 72.6424C70.4385 72.8527 70.3147 73.0859 70.2777 73.3422C70.2408 73.5893 70.2817 73.8456 70.4004 74.1112C70.519 74.3768 70.7109 74.6425 70.976 74.9083C71.2594 75.1924 71.5361 75.3918 71.806 75.5065C72.0804 75.6167 72.3411 75.6491 72.5883 75.6036C72.8355 75.5582 73.0532 75.4417 73.2411 75.2543C73.3923 75.1035 73.5229 74.9091 73.6331 74.6713C73.7432 74.4334 73.8305 74.1589 73.895 73.8478L74.595 73.9997C74.5395 74.439 74.4315 74.8302 74.2709 75.1732C74.1103 75.5163 73.9086 75.8089 73.6657 76.0512Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="importance_e" d="M80.0465 70.015C79.6423 70.2196 79.2404 70.3143 78.8409 70.2989C78.4384 70.2778 78.0629 70.1378 77.7142 69.8791C77.3656 69.6203 77.0641 69.2397 76.8098 68.7373C76.5496 68.2234 76.4154 67.7363 76.4073 67.2762C76.405 66.813 76.5187 66.4 76.7485 66.037C76.9811 65.6653 77.3255 65.364 77.7816 65.1331C78.2147 64.9138 78.6123 64.825 78.9743 64.8666C79.3392 64.8995 79.6655 65.0353 79.9533 65.2742C80.241 65.513 80.4829 65.8258 80.6787 66.2127C80.7226 66.2993 80.7636 66.3874 80.8016 66.4769C80.8397 66.5665 80.8764 66.6676 80.9117 66.7803L77.6895 68.4116L77.3562 67.7533L79.6689 66.5825L79.5871 66.7218C79.476 66.4879 79.3447 66.2932 79.1934 66.1377C79.0479 65.9792 78.881 65.8787 78.6926 65.8362C78.5043 65.7938 78.3004 65.8281 78.0809 65.9392C77.8326 66.0649 77.6627 66.2379 77.5712 66.4584C77.4854 66.6759 77.465 66.9221 77.5098 67.1968C77.5603 67.4687 77.6616 67.7547 77.8137 68.055C77.9803 68.3841 78.1712 68.6538 78.3865 68.864C78.5988 69.0685 78.8339 69.1961 79.0918 69.2469C79.3497 69.2977 79.6201 69.2515 79.903 69.1083C80.1051 69.0059 80.3056 68.8573 80.5043 68.6624C80.7031 68.4675 80.89 68.2277 81.0651 67.9432L81.7053 68.3264C81.4902 68.7182 81.2415 69.0581 80.9593 69.3461C80.6741 69.6283 80.3699 69.8513 80.0465 70.015Z" fill="#E31919"/>

<path id="support_s" d="M151.387 71.782C151.204 71.9014 151.09 72.0573 151.045 72.2497C151.006 72.4384 151.006 72.6501 151.046 72.8848C151.089 73.1252 151.146 73.3808 151.218 73.6517C151.298 73.9246 151.367 74.1973 151.423 74.47C151.483 74.7483 151.507 75.0216 151.496 75.2899C151.488 75.5639 151.418 75.8251 151.288 76.0734C151.163 76.3181 150.949 76.5393 150.647 76.737C150.231 77.0094 149.818 77.125 149.408 77.0837C149.002 77.0481 148.616 76.8936 148.25 76.6202C147.887 76.3525 147.566 76.0049 147.286 75.5772C147.092 75.2807 146.924 74.9552 146.781 74.6005C146.637 74.2553 146.527 73.8953 146.453 73.5204L148.038 72.5445L148.441 73.1603L147.486 74.0168L147.607 73.7911C147.641 74.0295 147.701 74.2634 147.786 74.4928C147.876 74.7185 147.983 74.9254 148.106 75.1136C148.259 75.3474 148.429 75.5378 148.615 75.6849C148.81 75.834 149.011 75.9227 149.216 75.9509C149.428 75.9754 149.633 75.9223 149.833 75.7917C150.027 75.6648 150.146 75.5052 150.191 75.3128C150.246 75.1224 150.252 74.907 150.208 74.6666C150.174 74.4281 150.116 74.1772 150.033 73.9138C149.956 73.6466 149.885 73.3758 149.819 73.1011C149.759 72.8228 149.73 72.5485 149.732 72.2782C149.744 72.01 149.81 71.7554 149.929 71.5145C150.058 71.2755 150.276 71.0553 150.584 70.8538C150.971 70.6001 151.352 70.4852 151.726 70.5092C152.106 70.5294 152.465 70.661 152.803 70.9039C153.147 71.1431 153.451 71.4651 153.716 71.8699C153.903 72.155 154.066 72.472 154.204 72.821C154.353 73.1719 154.465 73.5424 154.541 73.9324L153.039 74.7928L152.625 74.1598L153.485 73.3649L153.441 73.5771C153.403 73.3821 153.343 73.185 153.262 72.9859C153.184 72.7924 153.087 72.6073 152.972 72.4306C152.837 72.2253 152.682 72.0501 152.505 71.905C152.335 71.7561 152.154 71.6667 151.963 71.6367C151.773 71.6067 151.58 71.6552 151.387 71.782Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_u" d="M154.316 84.5026C154.151 84.0768 154.147 83.6693 154.303 83.28C154.468 82.8946 154.827 82.5949 155.38 82.3809L158.249 81.2702L158.122 81.451L158.038 80.5845L158.629 80.3557L159.397 82.141L156.013 83.451C155.689 83.5764 155.476 83.743 155.374 83.9506C155.28 84.1622 155.281 84.3919 155.377 84.6397C155.451 84.8304 155.583 85.0204 155.773 85.2098C155.964 85.3992 156.214 85.5653 156.525 85.7079L156.273 85.707L159.514 84.4524L159.358 84.6443L159.274 83.7778L159.865 83.549L160.633 85.3343L156.153 87.0686L156.288 86.8518L156.386 87.7565L155.795 87.9852L155.124 86.4478L155.995 85.9241L156.001 86.1083C155.566 85.9111 155.206 85.6704 154.921 85.3863C154.638 85.1086 154.436 84.814 154.316 84.5026Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_p" d="M156.372 93.6086L156.998 93.5081L157.401 94.344L157.163 94.2166L163.461 93.2055L163.314 93.3844L163.406 92.4792L164.032 92.3787L164.379 94.0209L163.523 94.3032L163.573 94.1606C163.905 94.4248 164.17 94.6963 164.366 94.9753C164.563 95.2543 164.687 95.5519 164.737 95.8682C164.8 96.2584 164.751 96.6183 164.59 96.9478C164.435 97.2762 164.17 97.557 163.793 97.79C163.424 98.0287 162.954 98.1939 162.382 98.2857C161.736 98.3894 161.18 98.3648 160.714 98.2119C160.249 98.0658 159.873 97.812 159.588 97.4507C159.31 97.0951 159.128 96.6548 159.044 96.13C159.016 95.9551 159.001 95.7746 158.999 95.5887C158.996 95.4027 158.999 95.2055 159.007 94.9972L159.185 95.1344L157.358 95.4277L157.527 95.2556L157.442 96.2734L156.816 96.3739L156.372 93.6086ZM159.888 95.8393C159.97 96.3506 160.203 96.7032 160.586 96.8971C160.969 97.0909 161.46 97.1398 162.058 97.0436C162.449 96.981 162.777 96.8765 163.043 96.7302C163.311 96.5907 163.508 96.421 163.635 96.2212C163.761 96.0214 163.805 95.7971 163.765 95.5481C163.733 95.353 163.647 95.1564 163.504 94.9584C163.37 94.7661 163.177 94.5728 162.925 94.3786L163.282 94.4765L159.669 95.0566L159.887 94.8663C159.842 95.2324 159.842 95.5567 159.888 95.8393Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_p" d="M156.903 105.184L157.536 105.212L157.762 106.113L157.555 105.94L163.927 106.224L163.747 106.369L164.021 105.502L164.654 105.53L164.661 107.208L163.766 107.312L163.843 107.182C164.115 107.508 164.319 107.827 164.455 108.14C164.591 108.453 164.652 108.77 164.638 109.09C164.62 109.485 164.499 109.827 164.275 110.117C164.058 110.408 163.741 110.629 163.325 110.781C162.915 110.94 162.421 111.007 161.842 110.981C161.189 110.952 160.649 110.815 160.224 110.571C159.798 110.334 159.481 110.009 159.275 109.597C159.074 109.193 158.986 108.725 159.01 108.194C159.018 108.017 159.039 107.837 159.075 107.655C159.11 107.472 159.153 107.28 159.203 107.077L159.349 107.247L157.5 107.165L157.701 107.031L157.412 108.01L156.778 107.982L156.903 105.184ZM159.895 108.08C159.872 108.598 160.028 108.99 160.364 109.257C160.7 109.525 161.171 109.672 161.777 109.699C162.172 109.716 162.514 109.681 162.805 109.591C163.095 109.509 163.322 109.382 163.487 109.212C163.651 109.042 163.739 108.831 163.75 108.58C163.759 108.382 163.714 108.172 163.615 107.949C163.522 107.734 163.372 107.505 163.164 107.264L163.494 107.432L159.839 107.269L160.091 107.127C159.973 107.477 159.907 107.794 159.895 108.08Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_o" d="M162.938 121.459C162.744 122.225 162.362 122.761 161.793 123.067C161.228 123.38 160.523 123.43 159.677 123.216C159.09 123.067 158.611 122.833 158.242 122.514C157.871 122.202 157.619 121.822 157.487 121.374C157.353 120.932 157.355 120.44 157.492 119.899C157.685 119.139 158.063 118.606 158.625 118.299C159.187 117.998 159.893 117.956 160.746 118.172C161.333 118.321 161.813 118.552 162.184 118.863C162.554 119.175 162.807 119.552 162.941 119.994C163.075 120.436 163.074 120.924 162.938 121.459ZM162.101 121.184C162.207 120.767 162.125 120.409 161.857 120.109C161.587 119.816 161.132 119.588 160.491 119.425C159.85 119.263 159.355 119.246 159.006 119.376C158.657 119.505 158.431 119.771 158.329 120.174C158.255 120.465 158.267 120.724 158.364 120.953C158.467 121.183 158.648 121.384 158.907 121.555C159.173 121.727 159.513 121.867 159.929 121.972C160.55 122.13 161.04 122.138 161.4 121.997C161.764 121.864 161.998 121.593 162.101 121.184Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_r" d="M154.532 129.675L155.069 130.011L154.81 130.85L154.71 130.643L158.176 132.811L157.918 132.819L158.578 132.207L159.116 132.543L158.296 134.008L157.377 133.626L157.499 133.509C157.608 133.939 157.656 134.323 157.645 134.662C157.637 135.01 157.54 135.331 157.356 135.626C157.24 135.811 157.09 135.986 156.906 136.152L155.459 135.15L155.838 134.544L156.841 135.003L156.574 134.968C156.607 134.94 156.639 134.908 156.67 134.871C156.701 134.835 156.73 134.796 156.755 134.756C156.878 134.559 156.938 134.328 156.936 134.061C156.936 133.804 156.888 133.541 156.791 133.271L157.023 133.537L154.059 131.683L154.305 131.656L153.562 132.42L153.025 132.084L154.532 129.675Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="support_t" d="M146.526 140.751C146.77 140.398 147.064 140.199 147.409 140.156C147.759 140.117 148.15 140.246 148.582 140.545L151.314 142.434L151.073 142.478L151.648 141.646L152.195 142.024L151.781 142.981L151.71 142.707L152.845 143.492L152.318 144.631L151.006 143.724L151.23 143.706L150.335 145L149.666 144.513L150.549 143.235L150.611 143.451L148.013 141.655C147.772 141.488 147.569 141.41 147.405 141.421C147.24 141.431 147.103 141.515 146.995 141.672C146.929 141.767 146.874 141.882 146.83 142.018C146.786 142.153 146.745 142.303 146.706 142.466L146.018 142.276C146.077 141.663 146.247 141.154 146.526 140.751Z" fill="#2919E3"/>

<path id="diamond" d="M73.6465 108.253L110.253 71.6465L146.859 108.253L110.253 144.859L73.6465 108.253Z" fill="#FEFEFE" stroke="#8A2BE2" stroke-width="2.32854"/>

<path id="P" d="M101.563 121.882H106.718V112.268H112.164C118.735 112.268 122.264 108.322 122.264 102.848C122.264 97.4156 118.777 93.4282 112.233 93.4282H101.563V121.882ZM106.718 108.03V97.7351H111.441C115.304 97.7351 117.013 99.8191 117.013 102.848C117.013 105.877 115.304 108.03 111.469 108.03H106.718Z" fill="#8A2BE2"/>

</svg>
        </div>
        <div class="slidecontainer">
          <input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" class="supSlider" id="supRange">
          <p>Support: <span id="supOutput"></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>
    </div>
```

## Javascript

```js
    var scoreInt = 0;
    var score = document.getElementById("score");
    var impSlider = document.getElementById("impRange");
    var impOutput = document.getElementById("impOutput");
    impSlider.oninput = function () {
      impOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
      scoreInt = parseInt(impOutput.innerHTML) * parseInt(supOutput.innerHTML);
      score.innerHTML = scoreInt.toString();
      switch (this.value) {
        case "0":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "1":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "2":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "3":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "4":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "5":
          document.getElementById("I1").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I2").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I3").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I4").style.fill = "red";
          document.getElementById("I5").style.fill = "red";
          break;
      }

    }
    impOutput.innerHTML = impSlider.value;

    var supSlider = document.getElementById("supRange");
    var supOutput = document.getElementById("supOutput");

    supSlider.oninput = function () {
      switch (this.value.toString()) {
         case "0":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
          case "1":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "2":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "3":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "none";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "4":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "none";
          break;
        case "5":
          document.getElementById("S1").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S2").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S3").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S4").style.fill = "blue";
          document.getElementById("S5").style.fill = "blue";
          break;
      }
    }
```

## CSS

```css
    body {
      padding: 0;
    }

    

    .gear {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    }

    .dia {
      fill: rgba(171,25,200, .86);
    }

    .imp::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      background: red;
    }

    .sup::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      background: blue;
    }

    .slidecontainer {
      width: 20%;
      padding-top: 0;
    }

    .impSlider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25px;
      background: #d3d3d3;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }

      .impSlider:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .impSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: red;
      }

    .supSlider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25px;
      background: #d3d3d3;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }

      .supSlider:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .supSlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: blue;
      }

    .impSlider[type="range"] {
      transform: rotate(270deg);
      position: absolute;
      top: 200%;
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
    }

    .supSlider[type="range"] {
      width: 200px;
      height: 20px;
    }
```

## edit 1:

so it should work with touch by default.

[Video Example](https://watch.screencastify.com/v/EiP1NhECI6DGAVrOVNHb)

Comment: This is working, so just do the same for the red side, hope this helps, peace out.

Comment: just note what code I removed.

Comment: I'm not really sure what this does, but the tap feature is not there. At least as far as I can tell.

Comment: Maybe someone can explain how this works. https://jsfiddle.net/kxj9t2e6/

I pretty much need this but when the user clicks, it changes colors and click again to change back.

Comment: @r00key  [try this](https://jsfiddle.net/ptcdhu8f/1/) look at the line 22 on the javascript